# Grep all strings from several binary files into one txt file

Tags: shell-script, grep, string, binary

I've decided to play around dumping all process memory of couple utilities in order to find out, how much trace of sensitive info an attacker could theoretically obtain from app's memory.

I've found this one-liner for dump purposes:

```
grep rw-p /proc/$1/maps | sed -n 's/^\([0-9a-f]*\)-\([0-9a-f]*\) .*$/\1 \2/p' | while read start stop; do gdb --batch --pid $1 -ex "dump memory $1-$start-$stop.dump 0x$start 0x$stop"; done
```

Unfortunately, I do not use Bash fluently and faced with a lot of spawned by this script dump files(all about kilobytes sized).

So, my question is: how can I use `strings` command line tool in order to grep all null terminated strings to one file?

So, I wrote something like this(goes in infinite loop without any result):

```
for f in *.dump; do strings $1 > foo.txt; done
```

I know, that this one liner is close to my goal, but I can't finally make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this.  Use of ">>" to append to file rather than overwriting the file each time.

```
rm foo.txt
for f in *.dump; do strings $f >> foo.txt; done
```

To aid your reviewing, you might want to also pipe it through "sort -u" to remove any duplicates.

Might take a while to run if you've many large .dump files.

Comment: Cheers! Next time I should be more attentive